# what is this iPhone UI technique called?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In iPhone UI terms, what's the name of the effect that causes additional options to appear when you tap-and-hold an element?

For example, when you hold down the "e" keyboard key for a moment, causing the additional accent mark buttons to appear.

Is there an established approach to implementing this effect, or should I code it up from scratch?

Comment: I've heard it called many things. "Long press" seems the most popular.  "Long click" doesn't really make sense since touchscreens dont click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen it referred as `touch and hold`. About implementing it, I'm thinking about a no-repeat NSTimer that fires a certain amount of time from your *touchDown* event, and invalidates on *touchUpInside* or *touchUpOutside*, in case you stop the touch before the amount of time elapses.

Comment: Yeah, that's the approach I was going to take. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I would call that `hover`...but I don't know if there's a standard or built in way to do it (sorry). Or for an OS9 throw back you could call it `click and hold`.

Answer (score 1):

Umm… maybe an UICallout view, but those are forbidden. As seen in maps when you select a location.